# Routing between two NICs same PC

Tags: windows, routing, wireshark

I have two NICs, `192.168.56.0/24` and my wifi NIC `192.168.1.0/24`. Can I route between these two NICs to be able to ping from my Physical HOST to any host on `192.168.56.0/24` while using VMs?

I know there are many other ways but I need that way because I run IOU integrate it with GNS3-Remote server and I want to capture traffic and send it to my Desktop. Also, I know I can use UNL but for now I need to have a route between these two NICs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it on windows, you can add a static route to each of your interfaces.

You'll have to add static routes to the IP Networks at each NIC from command prompt (or make a batch file to use only when required) :

**route add** *destination-address* **mask** *subnet-mask gateway-ip*

OR

**route add** *destination-address* **mask** *subnet-mask interface-index-number*

Done!

---

Or if you need to use GNS3, you can try this out.

**You can stop here if you already know how.**

Place a router and connect two clouds to two of the router's interfaces. At the cloud configuration, assign each cloud an NIC from your PC. So now you have one cloud connected to each of the PCs NIC cards. Assign IP addresses on router and clouds. This basically results in both networks at your PC's NICs being connected to your router in GNS3.

Voila! You now have routing between your networks.